# Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of an abelian group $G$ and let $HK = \{ab \mid a \in H, b \in K \}$. Prove that $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I'm struggling pretty hard with this one. I know $H$ and $K$ being abelian must be a key, because the next question asks to show that if they arent this isnt true, but I cant seem to put the pieces together. I know I just need to show $HK$ is closed and contains the inverses. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Well, why not start by showing that $HK$ is closed and contains the inverses?  Start with "closed" say.  Suppose $g_1,g_2\in HK$ .  Can you show that $g_1g_2\in HK$?

Comment: Write down the product of two typical elements of $HK$ and see if you can show it's in $HK$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g_1,g_2\in HK,$ then $g_1=h_1k_1,$ and $g_2=h_2k_2,$ for some $h_1,h_2\in H,$ and some $k_1,k_2\in K,$ and

$$g_1g_2=h_1k_1h_2k_2=h_1h_2k_1k_2\in HK,$$
by way of $G$ being abelian.

Use this idea to finish the proof.

Comment: thanks, I think I see it!. I know $h_1h_2$ are in H because its closed. Same for K. I can do same for inverse correct? $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1} = a^{-1}b^{-1}$

Comment: Right idea. Now do it with an arbitrary element $a^{-1}b$ where $a\in HK$ and $b\in HK,$ and follow the same pattern I set forth about what you can say about $a,$ and $b.$

Comment: You might also want to show that if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $K$ is any other subgroup that $HK$ is a subgroup of $G.$